# How to call Angular JS controller method from outside and perform data binding?

Tags: angularjs

I was able to call the Angular JS controller method from outside JS method.. However any change to the data is not reflecting in the data binding...

```
enter code here

applicantInfo.controller('testController', function($scope, $http,$timeout) {  
$http.get("XXX").success(function (response) {$scope.data-bding= response;});
/* This is fine*/
/* below is called from outside controller*/
$scope.loadFocusData = function () {
    $http.get(XXXX).success(function(response) {

        $timeout(function() {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response)); // I can see the JSON response printing
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                this.data-bdingin= response; // does not happen
               });
            });
    });
};
```

JS calling the Controller method

```
var scope = angular.element('XXXX').scope();

scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.XXXX = XXXX;
    scope.loadFocusData();
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: What do you mean "called from outside controller"?

Comment: I have another browser app the sends events across...those are called from regualr JS method `var scope = angular.element('XXXX').scope(); scope.$apply(function(){
  scope.XXXX = XXXX;
  scope.loadFocusData();
  
  });` this is the JS method that is trying to call controller method to refresh the data.

Comment: You don't need `$timeout` or `$scope.$apply` when using `$http`.

Comment: `data-bding` is not a legal variable in javascript, would you try `data_binding`?

Comment: Please post all your relevant code in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: that is just to show the some variable in controller scope is getting assigned with some value

Comment: If you using `$http` and you mention two apps i presume you have two independent Angular apps that you want to communicate with each-other? If so does this mean you've got access to the `$scope` of a controller from app 2 in app 1 ?!?

Comment: `angular.element().scope()` should only be used for debugging.

Comment: second app is not an angular js app..it is old legacy web app. So If angular.element is only debugging purpose..what are my options for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like..I just need to define using parent scope using " scope: false", so the data can be shared across and transclude : true...so the outside world can update data. There are other options too, this may have side effects depending what you are trying to do.